# How does Apache Ant resolve duplicate targets

Tags: apache, ant

Say I have two targets in ant with the same name in two different build files but, one is imported into the other.

build.xml

```
<project>
    <target name="once">
        <echo>once</echo>
        </target>

        <target name="twice">
            <echo>twice-a in build.xml</echo>
            </target>
        <!-- duplicate target twice imported again from build2.xml -->
        <import file="build2.xml"/>

</project>
```

build2.xml

```
<project>

    <target name="twice">
        <echo>twice-a in build2.xml</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

How does ant resolve duplicate targets ?

If it had been in a single file it would have a duplicate target thrown an error however since its imported its not throwing an error.

When I run `ant twice` I get

```
$ ant twice
Buildfile: /Users/nav/Codes/build.xml

twice:
     [echo] twice-a in build.xml

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

If ant does take the first declaration as the target then why doesn't moving the import statement up in build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project>
    <!-- import moved to the top -->
    <import file="build2.xml"/>

    <target name="once">
        <echo>once</echo>
        </target>

        <target name="twice">
            <echo>twice-a in build.xml</echo>
            </target>
</project>
```

still outputs the same as

```
$ ant twice
Buildfile: /Users/nav/Codes/build.xml

twice:
     [echo] twice-a in build.xml

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign project names, then you can access the both targets

```
<project name="build1">
<target name="once">
    <echo>once</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="twice">
        <echo>twice-a in build.xml</echo>
        </target>
    <!-- duplicate target twice imported again from build2.xml -->
    <import file="build2.xml"/>

</project>
```

Build2

```
<project name="build2">

 <target name="twice">
     <echo>twice-a in build2.xml</echo>
  </target>

</project>
```

call ant -p

```
    Buildfile: build.xml

Main targets:

Other targets:

 build2.twice
 once
 twice
```

If not project name is assign the imported target are hidden if they have the same name.

Comment: so its not like overriding properties wherein the precedence order of the property statement matters but in the case of targets its the project name...thanks